# как можно в python открывать, редактировать, и сохранять графические файлы?

Tags: python, изображения

я знаю, что для работы с файлами в python используется функция open, но как с помощью нее или без ее помощи прямо в программе редактировать файлы, например, с расширением .png

Answer (score 11):

Как я понимаю, по-разному. Вот, к примеру, с использованием библиотеки PIL(python imaging library):

```
# конвертируем картинку
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.open('pic.png') # открываем PNG
img.save('pic.gif') # сохраняем как GIF

# создаем картинку, пишем в неё текст и сохраняем
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
text = "Abracadabra :)" # готовим текст
color = (0, 100, 100) # создаем цвет
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 100), color) # создаем изображение 
imgDrawer = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
imgDrawer.text((10, 20), text) # пишем на изображении наш текст
img.save("pic.png") # сохраняем в PNG

# проводим манипуляции с картинкой, получаем ее свойства
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw 
img = Image.open('pic.png') #открываем изображение
format = img.format #формат изображения
size = img.size #размер изображения
histogram = image.histogram() # получаем гистограмму
```

Библиотека позволяет осуществлять массу манипуляций с графическими форматами. Рекомендую также её форк - [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io): как минимум, интересна существенно возросшей скоростью (для нас еще тем, что подддерживает, в отличие от PIL, формат PNG с одного из наших приборов).

**Предупреждения:**

1. в версии Pillow 5.0 прекратилась поддержка питона 3.3!
2. начиная с версии Pillow 5.3.0 наблюдается "странная" работа с многостраничными TIFF-файлами. Пока не разобрались, в чём
   же дело. Так что, если вы работаете с подобным форматом, рекомендую пока не
   пользовать версии 5.3.0 и выше
3. **(новое)**  В версии Pillow 6.0.0 прекратилась поддержка питона 3.4! Если зачем-то предпочитаете оставаться на 3.4, пользуйтесь версией 5.4.1
4. **(новое)**  В версии Pillow 6.0.0 убран ряд функций, ранее объявленных устаревшими. Большинство из них реализовано в модуле **ImageFilter**.
5. **(новое)**  Собственно, таблица совместимости Pillow и версий питона:
   [image: Совместимость версий библиотеки и языка]